# Inserción en BD a través de campos de un Servicio Web

Tags: sql, xml, webservice, wso2

estoy realizando un servicio web y quiero hacer lo siguiente:

El cliente envia una petición y dependiendo de lo introducido en los campos nombre y/o apellidos, es decir, si introduce un nombre que ya estaba en BD responderá el servicio un mensaje y si es la primera vez que se introduce ese nombre lo introduce a la BD y el servicio responde con otro mensaje.

Pero mi duda está, en que si por ejemplo no introduzco ningún valor al apellido (ver resultado línea 1 de BD), me inserta lo siguiente en Base de Datos y a mi me gustaría que me recogiese el campo apellidos o nombre (dependiendo del campo dejado a blanco) en blanco al no habersele insertado ningún valor. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Esta es la imagen del servicio:
[image: Cliente]

Esta es la imagen de lo recogido en Base de datos:
[image: Base Datos]

Mi código XML es:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence 
  name="ServicioClientes_IN_SEQ" 
  trace="disable" 
  xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" 
  onError="ServicioClientes_FAULT_SEQ">

  <log level="full"/>
  <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" scope="default"
    type="STRING" value="true"/>
 
 <log>
  <property name="INICIO" value="ServicioClientes_IN_SEQ"></property>
 </log>
 
 <property name="AUDIT_NAME" scope="default" type="STRING" value="AUDIT_ServicioClientes"/>
<!--     <sequence key="GeneralAudit_INIT_SEQ"/>
 --> 
  <!-- Validar XSD -->
  <validate>
      <schema key="conf:/esbResources/ServicioClientesv01/schemas/ServicioClientes_v1.0.0.xsd"></schema>
      <on-fail>
         <property name="ERROR_CODE" value="400"></property>
         <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" value="Error de validacion de mensaje"></property>
         <sequence key="ServicioClientes_FAULT_SEQ"></sequence>
         <drop></drop>
      </on-fail>
   </validate>
   <property xmlns:urn="urn:juntadeandalucia:ceice:intersae:type:v1.0.0" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" name="ID_STO" expression="//urn:id_sto" scope="default" type="STRING"></property>
   <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"></property>
   <property name="messageType" value="application/xml" scope="axis2"></property>
   <dblookup>
      <connection>
         <pool>
            <dsName>INTERSAE</dsName>
         </pool>
      </connection>
      <statement>
         <sql>
            <![CDATA[SELECT COUNT(*) AS NOMBRE FROM CLIENTE_INFO WHERE NOMBRE = ?]]></sql>
            <parameter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:p="urn:juntadeandalucia:ceice:intersae:type:v1.0.0" expression="//p:nombre" type="CHAR"></parameter>
            <result name="nom" column="NOMBRE"></result>
         </statement>
      </dblookup>
      <log>
         <property name="Cuenta" value="nom"></property>
      </log>
      <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" source="$ctx:nom&gt;0" regex="true">
         <then>
            <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
               <format>
                  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:juntadeandalucia:ceice:intersae:type:v1.0.0">
                     <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
                     <soapenv:Body>
                        <response>DUPLICADO</response>
                     </soapenv:Body>
                  </soapenv:Envelope>
               </format>
            </payloadFactory>
         </then>
         <else>
            <dbreport>
               <connection>
                  <pool>
                     <dsName>INTERSAE</dsName>
                  </pool>
               </connection>
               <statement>
                  <sql>
                     <![CDATA[INSERT INTO CLIENTE_INFO(NOMBRE, APELLIDOS) VALUES(?, ?)]]></sql>
                     <parameter xmlns:p="urn:juntadeandalucia:ceice:intersae:type:v1.0.0" expression="//p:nombre" type="CHAR"></parameter>
                     <parameter xmlns:p="urn:juntadeandalucia:ceice:intersae:type:v1.0.0" expression="//p:apellidos" type="CHAR"></parameter>
                  </statement>
               </dbreport>
               <payloadFactory media-type="xml">
                  <format>
                     <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:juntadeandalucia:ceice:intersae:type:v1.0.0">
                        <soapenv:Header></soapenv:Header>
                        <soapenv:Body>
                           <response>NUEVO</response>
                        </soapenv:Body>
                     </soapenv:Envelope>
                  </format>
               </payloadFactory>
            </else>
         </filter>
         <respond></respond>
      </sequence>
```